# Why I can run the Apps from App Store without any Profile?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have recently running into some issues with the Provisioning Profile.

Now I understand to test my locally developed App on another iPad, I need to install the Provisioning Profile on that iPad.

But what about the Apps from App Store? Why I can run them without any Profile?

Thanks.

Comment: Apps from the app store are signed by Apple. iOS devices trust Apple's signature, so they can run apps signed by them. A provisioning profile is needed for the device to trust apps signed by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're digitally signed by Apple and partly encrypted using a unique key generated from info in your Apple ID account. When you download an app from the AppStore, the iOS kernel first signature checks the binary (it looks for Apple's valid digital signature), then decrypts the encrypted part of the binary (in fact that's the process which cracking applications is based upon).